# Use the Axiom of Regularity to prove $(A,B)\neq A$ and $(A,B)\neq B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Attempted proof:** Let $(A,B)=\{ \{A \},\{A,B \}\}$ be the ordered pair of A and B. Using double contention, for A to equal (A,B), there must happen that $A\subseteq(A,B)$ and $(A,B)\subseteq A$. But the second contention would imply $\{A\} \in A$ and thus $\{A\}\cap A \neq \emptyset$, which contradicts the axiom of regularity.

And that would be it. I'm confused by the notation: is the last part a correct implication of $\{A\} \in A$? What approach could there be for it to improve? Where can I start to get the second part going since $\{A\}\not\in B$? Should I use $\{A,B\}\in B$ and disprove it by the Axiom of Regularity?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The axiom of regularity implies that for any two sets $X,Y$, if $X\in Y$, then $Y\not\in X$ (can you show this?).  This is the simplest fact to use here.  Given that result, proceed to prove the desired inequalities by contradiction:

First, suppose that
$(A,B)\subseteq A$.
Then every element of $(A,B)$ is an element of $A$.  In particular, $\{A\}\in A$; since $A\in\{A\}$ as well, this is a contradiction.  We conclude that $(A,B)\not\subseteq A$ and hence that $(A,B)\neq A$.

Second, suppose that
$(A,B) \subseteq B$.
Then every element of $(A,B)$ is an element of $B$. In particular, $\{A,B\}\in B$; since $B\in\{A,B\}$ as well, this is also a contradiction.  We conclude that $(A,B)\not\subseteq B$ and hence that $(A,B)\neq B$.

Comment: Yes! That was one of my possible proofs. Thank you